# Can you refer to stew as "strong"?

Tags: word-usage

Google books [show](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22strong+stew%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsZPOUQNp0zFamqALJc4GpmLfNbpfA:1662140363098&ei=yz8SY5HIBczRqwHzvp3IDw&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjR2aKv0_b5AhXM6CoKHXNfB_k4FBDy0wN6BAgBEEQ&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25) a couple of matches throughout the pages, but not much.
However, *strong soup* seems [to have place](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22strong%20soup%22&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsacf4EG2Y6N7YTkS5x7eENm5ZaiqQ%3A1662139982199&ei=Tj4SY-HiC9SNwPAP4K6-qAM&ved=0ahUKEwjhwdL50fb5AhXUBhAIHWCXDzU4ChDh1QMICQ&uact=5&oq=%22strong%20soup%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ4AlY-BdgxxpoAHAAeACAAWGIAeAEkgEBOJgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books). Since these two are more or less alike, can you say *strong stew*?

Comment: A ***strong*** stew / soup would be unusual phrasing, to say the least. Idiomatically, it would almost always be a ***rich*** stew. Or maybe ***thick*** or ***spicy***, depending on exactly what you want to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you couldn't really describe a stew as being 'strong'.

There are some foods that can be directly described as strong, but these tend to be things that are known to have a particular quality that can in turn can be described as such (pungency, potency etc). For example, *cheeses* can be described as strong to denote their maturity. *Coffee* is described as strong to denote the strength of the roast or its concentration (the ratio of product to water).

A stew doesn't really have a particular quality that is known for strength, but you could say that any food has *a strong flavour*.

There are plenty of other words that might commonly describe a soup or a stew, such as *rich, thick, heavy, flavourful, spicy, nourishing* etc. All of which have different meanings. It just depends what you want to say.

Comment: But certainly a stew can have properties which one could describe as 'strong'? Like being spicy, or simply having a 'strong' taste, or the same way coffee can be strong? In that sense, it seems a stew can definitely be described as strong, I would surmise. (Also: you have a duplicate 'can' in the second sentence :)

Comment: @Joachim I'd have to disagree, Joachim. Native English speakers don't use 'strong' to denote the strength of spice. We would say a food is *spicy*, and perhaps add that it is 'quite spicy' or 'very spicy'. When foods are *extremely* spicy, such as those containing a lot of chilli peppers, we say 'hot' rather than 'strong'. It's also worth noting that, while many cultures have 'stews', in western cuisines a stew is not normally a spicy dish, and stews from other cuisines tend to have unique names.

Answer (score 1):

I recall that a piping hot, and substantial stew, the type one eats on a cold winter evening, is said to be

> **a hearty stew**

[Ngram reports](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strong%20stew%2C%20hot%20stew%2C%20hearty%20stew&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrong%20stew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chot%20stew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chearty%20stew%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstrong%20stew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chot%20stew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chearty%20stew%3B%2Cc0) that the adjectives *hot* and *hearty* are by far more commonly used with stew than *strong*.

- We wanted **a hearty stew**, not a soup, so delicate spring vegetables like asparagus and zucchini were immediately ruled out.
  *Best slow and easy recipes* Editor, Cook's Illustrated

[image]

And although there are a number of false positives for “strong stew” such as *a strong stew of trouble*, and *a strong stew-pan*; Google books also reveal legitimate instances.

- But he was so hungry he cared about little else than sitting on a wobbling stool at the old trestle table and **eating a strong stew** of vegetables flavored with onions and garlic, herbs and flower petals. (1998) *Wild* by Jill Barnett

However, these instances are so rare that I would suggest that the OP use instead  *hearty*, *spicy*, or just *tasty* to describe a very flavourful stew.